# How don i fix the blank output?

Tags: python

(Unfortunately I can show you my problem because this site doesn't allow images, so I'll do my best to explain it.)

First let's get this out the way: I'm poor I don't have a laptop or computer, I only have my galaxy s9+ android phone. There isn't a library for 6 miles and I don't have a license.

What I'm doing: I'm learning python on freecodecamp.com and I'm at the point where we're learning about `urllib` library and how it takes care of what the socket library does. I use pydroid 3 on my phone and typed in a test code (I just typed

```
New = urllib.request.urlopen("http://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt")
For line in New:
    print(line.decode().strip())
```

Obviously I import the `urllib` library but when I run the code I get a blank output. The site is up and running I know this not only from doing this with the socket library but also from typing it in my web browser.

Now what am I doing wrong? Everytime I try to ask a question about any type of programming question it always has to be worded or something dude allow me to actually quite literally show you my code from a screen shot.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: You are allowed to post an image. [Edit] your question and press the image button on the toolbar. You'll be able to either paste in an image or choose an already saved one, and it'll be uploaded to imgur. The URL will automatically be included in your post.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (I changed `For` to `for`), so there must be an issue on your end.

Comment: Do you have multiple loops? `New` is a response object that can only be iterated once in the way you've written it currently.

Comment: No I don't have multiple loops, its just the one. I dont know what wrong. Its just blank.

Comment: I faced no issues running this code on my machine and I even confirmed that the Pydroid3 app produces the same valid result (it prints out the 4 lines of text). If your internet connection is really weak, it might take a longer time for the response to be processed. How long have you tried waiting? Since you don't get an error, your app is able to connect to the internet at least.

Comment: Ngl i wait about 2 min. It usually connects and prints immediately. Maybe somethings wrong with my pydroid.